# LuaTeX library loading on Windows

Tags: luatex

The LuaTeX documentation says the following:

> Loading dynamic Lua libraries will fail if there are two Lua libraries
>   loaded at the same time (which will typically happen on win32, because
>   there is one Lua 5.3 inside LuaTEX, and another will likely be linked
>   to the dll file of the module itself).

The question simply is: How I can avoid this problem? I have compiled my own Lua outside of LuaTeX and then compiled other Lua modules against this Lua DLL with the accompanying .lib. Now I want to use this library also in LuaTeX, but I don't find ANY information on how to solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

I was not specific enough. My problem is exactly the one in the quote. I am on Windows and I get the `multiple lua vms detected` error, because I linked my modules DLL to the .lib of my self-compiled Lua and I'm trying to use this same DLL with LuaTeX. I already found out about `--shell-escape` and it finds my DLL at the normal `LUA_PATH`. But I don't know how to enable my DLL to be used with any Lua 5.3 there is.

Answer (score 3):

In TeX Live, kpse searches DLL by values of CLUAINPUTS, in the
case that kpse is used.
Default is

```
(1) current directory
(2) $BINDIR/$progname/lua//
(3) $BINDIR/$engine/lua//
(4) $BINDIR/lua//
```

If kpse is not used, DLL is searched, for example, in $BINDIR.
luatex uses kpse, and texlua does not use kpse by default,
of course texlua also uses kpse if initialized appropriately.
In recent luatex, the option

```
--shell-escape
```

is necessary
to load a DLL.

Comment: Please see my edit. I am exactly at the point where the DLL, it found, fails to load, because of `multiple vms detected` :/

Comment: In the case of TeX Live w32 (32bit),
define the names of lua-5.3.5 libraries as
`lua53.dll` and `lua53.lib`. Link your module with the
import library `lua53.lib`. Don't use your `lua53.dll`,
and use your module only.

Comment: I'm using MikTeX not TeX Live and I don't really understand your advice. I tried renaming the `lua53.dll` in my `PATH` directory. Then it throws a generic error, that it failed to load a sublibrary inside the DLL. The library I want to load is `luasec` with its `ssl.dll` and `ssl.https`.

Comment: Don't forget to build lua-5.3.5 library as a DLL:
Compile options may be:
`-DLUA_COMPAT_5_2=1 -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL=1 -DLUA_COMPAT_MODULE=1 -DLUA_COMPAT_LOADSTRING=1 -DLUAI_HASHLIMIT=6`

Comment: I did use `LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL`, but not the others.

Comment: I don't know internals of MikTeX, and my answer does not
apply to the MikTeX, sorry.